# How to run wikidPad on Fedora

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, fedora

I am trying to get [wikidPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) running on Fedora 27. According to the [installation wiki](http://trac.wikidpad2.webfactional.com/wiki/InstallLinux), it runs well on Linux. There is a section on getting it running in Fedora but it was written in 2007, and it does not work for me.

My setup:

- Fedora 27 + LXDE (64-bit, running in a virtualbox VM)
- WikidPad 2.2 source code zip (latest version from 2014)

Following the [fedora instructions](http://trac.wikidpad2.webfactional.com/wiki/InstallLinux#WikidPadonFedora7Dec.2007), I installed:

- python2-wxpython-3.0.2.0-21.fc27.x86_64
- wxGTK-gl-2.8.12-29.fc27.x86_64.rpm
- already have python2 and sqlite3 installed
- also installed as dependencies for the above packages: SDL, wxBase, wxGTK, wxBase3, wxGTK3, wxGTK3-gl, wxGTK3-media

I run it like this:

```
  fedora ~/doc/wikidpad$ python WikidPad.py
  /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion 'g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_set_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
```

At that point, it displays a splash screen and just hangs there until I kill it with Ctrl-C.

What is the correct procedure to get this running on Fedora? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That hanging on startup was a bug (regarding a gtk2/gtk3 conflict) that has been fixed in WikidPad in 2016.

For example read here: https://github.com/WikidPad/WikidPad/issues/1

Please use a more recent (or the current) version of WikidPad!